# how to set image in uiimageview with the help of array in table view

Tags: arrays, swift, image, uiimage, tableview

```
  var imgg = ["wall-wallpaper-500x500.jpg", "wall-wallpaper-500x500.jpg", "wall-wallpaper-500x500.jpg"] ... .. ...

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let userCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ViewTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ViewTableViewCell else {
              fatalError()
        }

      if indexPath.section == 0{
                  userCell.thirdlbl.text = names[indexPath.row]
                  userCell.firstlbl.text = android[indexPath.row]
                  userCell.secondlbl.text = "ios"
        userCell.buttonLabel.text = "Hello"
        userCell.img.image = imgg[indexPath.row] // Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage?'

              }
```

Comment: If your images are located at your asset `UIImage(named: imgg[indexPath.row])`

Answer (score 0):

```
userCell.img.image = UIImage(named: imgg[indexPath.row])
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you can not use a `String` where `UIImage` is expected. You need to update your code to something like this:

```
userCell.img.image = UIImage(named: imgg[indexPath.row])
```

**[Update]**

If using an image within the assets folder, these don’t normally have an extension, so you would reference them by the file name *(without the extension)*. In this case your code should be

```
 userCell.img.image = UIImage(named:“wall-wallpaper-500x500”)
```

Comment: but still there's no image showing in stimulator in uiimageview.

Comment: Is the image file located wtihin your app's `Assets.xcassets` folder?

Comment: Yes, in Assests.xcassets i've created new imageset in which i have put the picture.

Comment: What is the name of the image set?

Comment: Not the image file but the name of the assets, generally the asset file doesn’t have an extension just a name. If you used the same name as before the asset would be “ wall-wallpaper-500x500”

Comment: Separate question, is the `ViewTableViewCell` the standard class or did you customize it?